# VBA Macro that gets range of rows in column A and replace them with values in column B

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table which contains values in column A and B. I want to run a macro which pops out an interface which prompts me to enter range of rows and then get values in column B and replace values in column A for the given range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for your question

```
Sub Test()

Dim RangeX As Variant

RangeX = InputBox(" Enter Range of rows. For Example rows 3  & 4 Means 3-4")


Row1 = Left(Trim(RangeX), 1)
Row2 = Right(Trim(RangeX), 1)

For i = Row1 To Row2

Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
Cells(i, 3).Value = "Values Replaced"
Next

MsgBox "Process Completed"

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot..Its works but then i had another function which uses a morefunc add-in which is now giving this error "Cannot run the macro 'Morefunc.OnRecalc'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."...i think maybe its because i changed the file to macro enabled